# c# Declaration unknown number of matrix in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, matrix, declaration

i need to **declare 16x16 matrix** blocks in a loop. Because **i don't know** how many blocks i must create. It changes acording to width. I have a code like this and name of the blocks must go like this: 
**"block1, block2, block(i)"** 
How can i declare this blocks inside of a loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    int[,] block = new int[16, 16];
}
```

Comment: You could create a list of matrices. Something like `List<int[,]>`. This way you don't need a name for each one, you just refer to `block[1]`, `block[2]`, etc..

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand this. i need a code so i create 16x16 matrix for each i values. I will use this matrix in loops again later repeadetly. example width =10 ,i need 10 matrix 16x16 totaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<int[,]> blocks = new List<int[,]>();

for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
  blocks.Add(new int[16, 16]());
}
```

Instead of having a bunch of different matrices declared, you have a list of them. You then refer to each individual matrix by its index.

`Console.WriteLine(blocks[6][2, 13]);`

This would print whatever is in your 7th block matrix at index [2, 13].

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes , it works thank you. now i wonder can i do it 2d ? like blocks [x][y]=[4][2]

Comment: I don't see why not. I'm not exactly sure what you intend to do with it, so your syntax might need some work, but just experiment with it a bit.

Comment: i did it. i use this decleration **List<List<string[,]>> blocks = new List<List<string[,]**  and then used blocks[i][j][x, y] to acsess to indexes. it works now thank you